# How to custom Play/Pause image For HTML5 Audio Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

how could I make this happen? For example.....

Once I have clicked 'button play' the changes to 'button pause'
and once I have clicked 'button pause' the changes to 'button play'.

I want to custom audio tags,but I don't know how to make it.

I don't know how to use Javascript to switch image.

I trying to find a way,but I don't understand it. T-T

Below is what I using in html template:

```
    <button><img src="{% static "img/play.png" %}"></button>
    <button><img src="{% static "img/pause.png" %}"></button>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ song.song_file.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
    </audio>
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var track = document.getElementById('track');
    
    var controlBtn = document.getElementById('play-pause');
    
    function playPause() {
        if (track.paused) {
            track.play();
            //controlBtn.textContent = "Pause";
            controlBtn.className = "pause";
        } else { 
            track.pause();
             //controlBtn.textContent = "Play";
            controlBtn.className = "play";
        }
    }
    
    controlBtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
    track.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      controlBtn.className = "play";
    });
```

```css
    #player-container #play-pause {
      cursor: pointer;
      text-indent: -999999px;
      height:40px;
      width: 40px;
      background: #eb01a5;
      background-image: url('http://basichow.com/asserts/images/play.png');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-position:center;
      background-size:20px;
    }
    .play {
      background-image: url('http://basichow.com/asserts/images/play.png');
    }
    .pause {
       background-image: url('http://basichow.com/asserts/images/pause.png')!important;
    }
```

```html
    <audio id="track">
      <source src="http://basichow.com/asserts/interlude.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
    
    <div id="player-container">
      <div id="play-pause" class="play">Play</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks you very much